# C# Application will not Receive Serial Data Stream

Tags: c#, bluetooth, serial-port

I am developing a C# Windows Forms Application to communicate via a Bluetooth Connection with a Raspberry Pi Model 3. This connection is mimicked through a virtual serial port on the client machine. I am able to start a bluetooth connection within the C# program but I cannot receive any data from the program. When I use the program Putty, I can see that the data is transmitting on COM Port the way that I would like it to.

I also discovered a weird sort of glitch with the C# program. If i have the COM Port open on Putty and then start the C# program, an error will occur with the port.open() command since the port is reserved. So then if I close Putty and continue the C# application the data will stream perfectly to the program. Has anyone encountered this issue before? I've been at a bit of a loss for a few days now. The Code in my program is shown below:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using InTheHand.Net;
using InTheHand.Net.Sockets;
using InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth;
using System.Threading;

namespace GUIfromPI
{

    static class Program
    {
        //PC BT USB adapter
        private static BluetoothEndPoint EP = new BluetoothEndPoint(BluetoothAddress.Parse("##:##:##:##:##:##"), BluetoothService.BluetoothBase); //addressing the usb adapter used on the PC (endpoint)
        private static BluetoothClient BC = new BluetoothClient(EP);

        //Pi BT Adapter
        private static BluetoothDeviceInfo BTDevice = new BluetoothDeviceInfo(BluetoothAddress.Parse("##:##:##:##:##:##")); //addressing the BT adapter on the Rasperry Pi
       // private static NetworkStream stream = null;
        public static SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort(); //Bluetooth module mimics serial protocol by streaming data through the COM5 port in the host80 computer
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Executing Program...");
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            if (BluetoothSecurity.PairRequest(BTDevice.DeviceAddress, "1234"))//MY_PAIRING_CODE))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("PairRequest: OK");

                if (BTDevice.Authenticated)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Authenticated: OK");
                    BC.SetPin("1234");//pairing code
                    //BC.BeginConnect(BTDevice.DeviceAddress, BluetoothService.SerialPort, new AsyncCallback(Connect), BTDevice);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Authenticated:No");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("PairRequest: No");
            }
            //mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM5");

            SerialThreadFunction();
        }


        public static void SerialThreadFunction()
        {
            mySerialPort.PortName = "COM10";
            mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            mySerialPort.DtrEnable = true;
            mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;
            mySerialPort.ReadTimeout = 100000;
            mySerialPort.Open();
            //mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
            string mydata = "hello";
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(mySerialPort.ReadLine());
                mydata = mySerialPort.ReadLine();
            }
            mySerialPort.Close();
        } 


        private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                            object sender,
                            SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            Console.WriteLine("Data Received: ");
            Console.Write(indata);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** I just discovered that declaring my Bluetooth Endpoint, client, and device are interfering with reading off of my serial port. Since the bluetooth connection was already initialized previously, I was able to see the data on the port. Now for why it does this?

Comment: If someone does not get to this, hold tight for an answer from me later on today.

Comment: That would be amazing. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it seems you are not doing anything wrong. Inherently .NET cannot handle multiple ownership of the same port. When you declare your `SerialPort` instance and connect to say... *COM11*... You have given ownership of *COM11* solely to your `SerialPort` instance. In order to have access to *COM11* you will now need to provide a reference to that specific `SerialPort` object which has ownership of *COM11*.

In your case you are opening PuTTY and then running your program. Once PuTTY obtains access to the port, your program will not be able to do so. This is completely standard in the .NET framework. Now, there are other ways that you can get multiple accesses to a COM port, but I think that's outside the scope of this question. Here's a software that will allow you to run an application and sniff traffic over the port at the same time... [Free Serial Port Monitor](http://www.serial-port-monitor.com/). You can get this for free, and there is a better version for purchase that does all kinds of magic.

Here is a little algorithm for ensuring your port is opened properly, you may want to take this... modify it a little bit... and use it as the `Connect` method on your `BluetoothClient` class.

```
SerialPort port = null;
string error = string.Empty;
bool success = false;
int tries = 5;

foreach(var name in System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames())
{
    // try each port until you find an open one
    port.Name = name;

    // there is always a chance that the port is open
    // if trying some operations back-to-back
    // give it a few extra tries if necessary
    for (int i = tries; i > 0; --i)
    {
        try
        {
            // avoid the exception by testing if open first
            if (!port.IsOpen)
            {
                port.Open();
                success = true;
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
        {
            // sometimes the exception happens anyway, especially
            // if you have multiple threads/processes banging on the
            // ports
            error += e.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

In addition to all of this, you may want to watch that your `Bluetooth` classes are not claiming ownership of the port when you need to read it. That may be what's interfering with reading the port. You really should create one single class and call it say `BluetoothClient` or something, and have that single class be responsible for all the interactions with the `SerialPort` reference. This way you ensure that whether you want to send/receive on the port you will always have ownership.

Comment: Sorry about all the edits, accidentally posted something wrong and had to change it up...

Comment: @Frankn does this answer help you at all? Or can it be improved somehow?